# disable user (ssh) login on rhel 5

Tags: ssh, login, rhel5

Someone deactivated remote logins for a user, and I want to reactivate it. I can su into it, though.
However, I have no idea how to reactivate logins. I checked /etc/ssh/sshd_config, but there is no Allow Users section. I checked PAM, but couldn't find anything either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

passwd -u username

Maybe the user is locked.

Comment: That was it, thanks! Unfortunately, my Linux administration knowledge is rather limited.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean there is no AllowUsers directive currently in there b/c that looks like what you would want:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/openssh-deny-or-restrict-access-to-users-and-groups.html